# To_TimeStamp from Oracle to MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query that runs on Oracle.
How do I convert it to MsSql?
In MsSql there is no function to_timestamp

```
REM INSERTING into EXPORT_TABLE
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into O_PREDICTION_ENTRY (ID,PREDICTION_SET_ID,PREDICTION_ID,PRESENTED,SELECTED,ACCOUNT_ID,ACCOUNT_STATUS,TRANSACTION_ID,TRANSACTION_TYPE,DEVICE_ID,BIZ_CLASS,INSIGHT,SCORE,FUNCTIONALITY_ID,PERIOD_START_DATE,PERIOD_END_DATE,MERCHANT_CATEGORY_ID,MERCHANT_CATEGORY_GROUP_ID,ACCOUNT_CD_MATURITY_DATE,CARD_ID,CARD_EXPIRATION_DATE,CREATED,LAST_STATEMENT_DUE_DATE,COUNTRY_NAME,RANK,INSIGHT_ID,TEXT,PRESENTED_DATE,SELECTED_DATE,DISPLAY_DATE,GENERATED,IS_OPTIN,USER_ID,CHANNEL_NAME,SEGMENT,BUSINESS,LOB,RATING,PREFERENCE_TYPE,INSIGHT_TYPE,INSIGHT_BEHAVIOR_GROUP)
values ('bc8f20cb-01e3-4c0b-90e4-04ca1ac748f8','9de435a6-068d-490e-8689-6be093b85879','IntroducePersonetics_UC1',1,0,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,51,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,to_timestamp('03-JAN-2017 06:22:07.358000000','DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),null,null,1,'IntroducePersonetics',null,to_timestamp('03-JAN-2017 06:22:09.035000000','DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),null,to_timestamp('03-JAN-2017 06:22:09.035000000','DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SSXFF'),1,1,'B_1010','VANILLA_QA','VANILLA_QA',null,null,null,'hide',null,null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you would just replace the calls to `to_timestamp()`.  In SQL Server, it depends on the definition of the column.  If the column is declared as `datetime2`, then you can use:

```
'2017-01-03 06:22:07.358000000'
```

If it is `datetime`, then SQL Server only allows up to three decimal places:

```
'2017-01-03 06:22:07.358'
```

Note that in Oracle, I would recommend that you use a `timestamp` constant for this:

```
timestamp '2017-01-03 06:22:07.358000000'
```

rather than using non-standard formats that you then convert.